# Jquery Datepicker + Fulcalendar : Pass datepicker selected date into fulcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, fullcalendar, global

I'm trying to implement the datepicker and the fulcallendar together in a one interface like this http://edifyzone.net/docs/cal.png .

When I click on a date in datepicker plugin, I want to display the fulcallendar view for that selected date.

When I click on a date, I want to set the **theDate** global variable, so I can use it inside the fulcallendar code under **eventResources** section as my **selectedDate** parameter (I am posting this value to json-events).

For some reason **theDate** global variable is not updating. Always it displays the initial value even if I set **theDate** variable inside the **onSelect** callback in datepicker plugin.

But if I click on a cell it shows the updated(correct) value. (See in fulcalendar **select** callback function. I'm alerting theDate variable)

How can I fix this? Can someone help me out? My requirement is to post the **theDate** value into the json-events file. Thanks a lot.

```
   <script>
        $(function() {

            window.theDate = new Date();//Get todays date and initialize
            //I tried var theDate = new Date(); but didn't work


        //datepicker
        var datepicker = $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'yy-m-d',
            inline: true,
            numberOfMonths: [2, 1],
            showButtonPanel: true,
            onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {

                var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate'),
                        day = date.getDate(),
                        month = date.getMonth(),
                        year = date.getFullYear();

                window.theDate = dateText;// Set the theDate value onDate select
                selected.val(dateText);

                //set the calendar
                calendar.fullCalendar('gotoDate', year, month, day);

            }
        });//end datepicker

        //Fullcalendar
        var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {left: '',center: 'title',right: ''},
            select: function(start, end, allDay, event, resourceId) {
                alert(theDate); // this alert shows the correct updated date
            },
            resources: 'calendar/json-staff',
            eventSources: [
                {
                    url: 'calendar/json-events',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        //This theDate value is not being updated
                        selectedDate: theDate // get the global theDate value
                    },
                    success: function($data) {
                        console.log($data.responseText);
                        //alert($data);
                    },
                    error: function($data) {
                        console.log($data);
                        alert('Error: check the console!  ' + $data.responseText);
                    },
                    color: 'yellow',   // a non-ajax option
                    textColor: 'black' // a non-ajax option
                }
            ]
            //events: 'calendar/json-events'
        });




    });//end of jquery
</script>

<html>
        <table border="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td width="10%" valign="top">
                    <div id="datepicker"></div>
                </td>
                <td valign="top"><div id='calendar'></div></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem like this,

I place the fullCallender script inside the DatePicker's onSelect fucntion,

```
....
onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {

    //var d = new Date(dateText); // This line only worked for chrome ???
    var d = $(this).datepicker('getDate');

    //Fullcalendar
    $('#calendar').empty(); //clear the initial view
    calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

        //Full calendar suff here

    }); //Fullcalendar ends

    /*-------------------- Set the selected date ---------------------*/
    calendar.fullCalendar('gotoDate', d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate());

}//on select ends
.....
```